# Why onCreateOptionsMenu() mthod is not being called?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have following Activity class :

```
public class HomeActivity extends WebtrendsActivity implements
        OnClickListener, OnAudioFocusChangeListener,
        VideoFragment.OnContentVideoCompletionListener,
        WatchLiveFragment.OnContentVideoErrorListener {


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.browse, menu);
        mediaRouteMenuItem = CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), menu,
                R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The issue is when call this activity all activity method is being called except onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu).I am confused why its happening.Any help.Thanks in Advance.

this my browse.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <item android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="Chromecast"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

Comment: How are you creating menu in your activity?  This method won't be called until the menu is required.

Comment: if you are working with fragments you must call setHasOptionMenu(); in onCreate(); for this to be called

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the issue.I am using theme with noactionbar once i changed it to Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar, onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method being called.